# Is there a name for the not given/null/empty-problem?

Tags: architecture, anti-patterns

I work with code, where data is stored/exchanged in Hashtable/Dictionary/Associative-Array-like structures, like this

```
{
   'alpha': None,
   'bravo': '',
   # 'charlie' is not given
}
```

there is not much standartization, which field is 'given', and when given, if it may be given as None/Null/Nil or an empty string. As a result, the code is littered with checks like `if hasattr(obj, 'alpha')` and default fallbacks.

**Is there a name or slang term for this kind of (imho) anti-pattern?**

UPDATE:

it seems, currently there is no name, so i'd like to hear suggestions. Currently we have these:

- Incorporeal Horde (credits to psr)

Comment: I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern. In the real world, there are situations when something is missing, and situations when not. If a default values makes sense, okay, but what if it really is null/non-existent? Some people don't have a middle name, for example. How would you represent that? That's why I believe it's more of a search for a better programming model for this kind of scenarios. Like the null object pattern, the maybe monad, or whatever else exists out there.

Comment: Note that an empty string is a perfectly valid member of the set of all strings and is quite different from not having a string. It's like the difference between the 2 sentences: "I have 0 dollars." and "I won't tell you how many dollars I have."

Comment: Python has a default dictionary which allows you to avoid these checks. Haskell has monads which solve all problems of the humanity.

Comment: @Ionut: yes, there are situations, where 'something missing' is ok, but in my case, i think, it's more the case that one preferres to make 100 receivers tolerant for all possible bullshit than to make 1 or 2 senders obey to a format. The middle name (or generally every part of an address) is imho a classic case where '' is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ingo: yes, but the problem is, that in my codebase, these 'meanings' are ignored. Different parts of the application may all answer for the same Order: {'positions': None}, {'positions': []} or just {}.

Comment: This topic reminds me of the motto "**Be conservative in what you send; be liberal in what you accept**". Also known as the Robustness Principle or Postel's law. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle

Comment: _in my codebase, these 'meanings' are ignored. Different parts of the application may all answer for the same Order: {'positions': None}, {'positions': []} or just {}_ well for this kind of problems my label is **inconsistency**. Been using it for ages, never had problems communicating it to others. Highly recommended. I doubt that it categorises as anti-pattern though, in all my communications agreed perception was that it's just a defect (bug)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is such a name (I looked, but of course how can you find a lack of a name)?

I suggest the name "Incorporeal Horde", though I would apply it to the full collection of null or degenerate objects - zero size collections, null, undefined, nothing, None, NAN (arguably is a different kind of edge case), DBNull, void, empty string (arguably an empty collection special case), missing dictionary entries, etc.

And I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern, per se, but as an issue in software development, especially in the case where your programming environment requires you to write separate code for many of those cases.

Apologies for a fairly non informative answer, but I think it's the best that can be done.  Plus, if the world adopts a name due to your question it could become a correct answer.

Comment: I love "Incorporeal Horde".

Comment: Sounds like 'Magic the Gathering'. I Like it. +1.

Answer (score 0):

In F# this is provided through an [Option Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (similarly to earlier languages in the same family).  I have used the same concept in a C# project where I have a rule that I try to never return null from a function, but I return the `Option<T>` of that type of there's a possibility of a None value.  That way the calling code knows that it has to deal with that possibility in the return value.

I would prefer to have non-nullable reference types, just like we now have nullable value types, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, this is referred to as `undefined`, which is a unique sentinel value, distinct from `null`.

You get `undefined` by either evaluating the global variable `undefined`, or a property of an object, that is not defined or by evaluating a statement, that doesn't return a value, such as calls to functions, that don't return anything, or a block or a variable declaration (although those two aren't valid expressions, so you will only encounter that in a JavaScript REPL).

When the `undefined` value is coerced to be an `Object` it becomes `null`, but it is not `null`.

Here's a little illustration:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];//undefined
a[0];//1
a[4];//undefined

var o = { foo: "123" };//undefined
o.foo;//"123";
o.bar;//undefined

function bar() { return null; };//undefined
bar();//null
function foo() { /*just an empty block*/};//undefined
foo();//undefined

typeof undefined;//"undefined"
typeof null;//"object"
null == undefined;//true - that is because undefined is converted to an object for comparison and thus yields null
null === undefined;//false - because they are not the same
```

I think it is reasonable to call undefined values (in contrast to values defined to be `null`) undefined, if that is your question. Using a unique sentinel value to communicate the absence of a defined value is a workable solution for dynamic languages, although it is often poorly understood.